# Does a Schengen Residency permit function as a multi-entry visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration

Just to clarify, I am a non-EU & have no visa-free access to Europe nor UK.

However, I have been granted a 6 month UK visit visa & I intend to travel to Edinburgh for a week before flying to France (for 2 days of travel) and finally back to Switzerland.

Now, I am currently residing in Switzerland and have a Swiss residence permit. I understand that with it, we can visit other schengen countries (subject to 90/180).

What I would like to confirm is that during the validity of the permit, it functions as a "Multiple-entry visa" of sorts ? (to put it loosely). So in essence, with this permit (well within its validity) + my passport, I can leave Switzerland for UK and come back with no issues ? (I have a UK visa too of course).

Issues as in like gate agents asking for proof of visa etc. I understand that entry to the country ultimately lies with the immigration officers

Comment: yes, this is all fine

Comment: You do have a 'proper' residence permit, or do you just have a long-term type D visa? A type D visa also allows you to reside in Switzerland (up to one year) and is therefore often colloquially called a 'residence permit' even if there are relevant differences. A type D visa can have a restricted number of allowed entries, meaning that you will not be allowed to reenter the Schengen area if the allowed number of entries has been used up.

Answer (score 2):

The residence permit lets you enter and exit the Schengen Area during its validity, so yes, no problems entering France with it - on the trip back, you only clear immigration in France, and not Switzerland (as France-Switzerland flights are effectively domestic)